# How to detect which device from request?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I want to limit my user to use only up to maximum 2 devices. How can I detect the device from each request?

Like for example:
After 5 devices, the user is given an option to remove the previous device before accessing with the new device.

Comment: Assign each device an id? Perhaps you could use a long-lived cookie?

Comment: maybe limit the number of refresh tokens?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include a detailed description of what you are trying to do. Explain how you identify the user (not the device) in your system. Show your attempts on how you detect a specific device and how you want to block them somehow to your system.